# Can randperm() generate several random permutations?

Tags: matlab

In Matlab

> p = randperm(n,k) returns a row vector containing k unique integers selected randomly from 1 to n inclusive.

Can one call to randperm() return several rows of vectors, each of which is as above?
If not, is there other way to generate several random permutations?

Will avoiding loop necessarily be faster in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[RANDPERM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) itself returns only one permutation. If you want to avoid loop you can call it with ARRAYFUN:

```
Nperm = 5; 
N = 6;
result = arrayfun(@(x)randperm(N),(1:Nperm)','UniformOutput',0);
```

This will return Nperm x 1 cell array. To convert it to matrix you can use CELL2MAT:

```
result = cell2mat(result);
```

There is also [PERMS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) function that returns all permutations, but it only practical for a small numbers.

Check also FileExchange submissions [ALLCOMB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb), [PERMS](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32978-perms) and [others](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?term=tag%3a%22permutations%22).

Comment: Will avoiding lop necessarily be faster?

Comment: Not necessary, specially in this case arrayfun returns cell array that can slow things down. But you can test with tic/toc.

Answer (score 1):

If you require that all the permutations are mutually unique, then you could use the following

```
permN = 5; 
permK = 4; 
nPerms = 10;
nGoodPerms = 0;
nMaxFailedTries = 100; 
nFailedTries = 0;

permList = cell(nPerms, 1);

while nGoodPerms < nPerms && nFailedTries <= nMaxFailedTries
    candidatePerm = randperm(permN, permK);
    if any(cellfun(@(x)~isempty(x) && all(x == candidatePerm), permList))
        nFailedTries = nFailedTries + 1;
    else
        nGoodPerms = nGoodPerms + 1;
        permList{nGoodPerms} = candidatePerm;
    end
end

permList = cell2mat(permList{1:nGoodPerms});
```

Should probably chuck a warning in there (or error) if not all the requested permutations were generated. Also one could add a prior check to make sure `nPerms` is not stupidly large (i.e., more unique permutations than could ever be generated with the given `permN` and `permK`).

Answer (score 1):

**As for `p = randperm(n)`**:

In Matlab 2010a and older, input parameter `k` is not supported. If you look at `randperm`'s code

```
[~, p] = sort(rand(1,n));
```

you'll see that it's very easy to modify it so that it produces `m` permutations of `n` elements (the result now has size `m`x`n`):

```
[~, p] = sort(rand(m,n), 2);
```

**As for `p = randperm(n,k)`**:

I don't know how Matlab does it in this case, since my version doesn't support it. You could always do as above and then trim:

```
p = p(:,1:k);
```

Not very efficient for `k` much smaller than `n`, though.